# MacOS regex grep getting value between curly brace

Tags: json, macos, curl

I'm trying to get a curl response between {}. I have found and tested a regex command that works files with Sublime or an online tester.

The problem occurs when I try to execute it with grep from MacOS. I have installed the grep from the brew library, but even though the installation occurred 100%, the command doesn't work. Deleting all break lines of file/response (performing debug), the command works! But in my case, the curl response comes with break lines, so I should be able to handle it.

Could someone tell me why it is occurring with MacOS and how I can solve it?

Curl response:

```
HTTP/2 401 
www-authenticate: Digest realm="MMS Public API", domain="", nonce="8878t9jXCP7+", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth", stale=false
content-type: application/JSON
content-length: 106
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 3
date: Fri, 13 Jan 2023 17:04:03 GMT
server: envoy

HTTP/2 400 
date: Fri, 13 Jan 2023 17:04:04 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; include subdomains;
referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
x-content-type-options: nosniff
content-type: application/json
x-frame-options: DENY
content-length: 200
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 23
server: envoy

{
  "detail": "Cluster asdasdasd cannot be created in a paused state.",
  "error": 400,
  "errorCode": "CANNOT_CREATE_PAUSED_CLUSTER",
  "parameters" : [ "asdasdasd" ],
  "reason": "Bad Request"
}
```

I want to get only the following lines:

```
 {
      "detail": "Cluster asdasdasd cannot be created in a paused state.",
      "error": 400,
      "errorCode": "CANNOT_CREATE_PAUSED_CLUSTER",
      "parameters" : [ "asdasdasd" ],
      "reason": "Bad Request"
    }
```

My regexs:

```
{([\S\s]+)}
{[^{}]*}
```

Sublime response:

[image]

regextester.com result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rob, did you read my post? The image attached to the post regards the result of the internal test. All message was copied and pasted, following the How o Ask.

Comment: `grep` applies the pattern separately to each line, and picks out lines that contain a match. It will never find a match that spans multiple lines. That's just not what it's designed for. It's the wrong tool for the job. Also, `[\S\s]` is nonstandard, and may or may not work depending on the specific regex engine being used.

Answer (score 0):

### Better use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/).

Your input are plain [JSON](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation).

Example to retrieve `errorCode`:

```
curl ...... | jq '.errorCode'
```

> `jq` is like `sed` for `JSON` data - you can use it to slice and filter and map and transform structured data with the same ease that `sed`, `awk`, `grep` and friends let you play with text.

### Or [gron](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron)

```
curl ...... | gron | awk -F' = ' '/^json.errorCode /{print $2}'
```

To install it:

```
go install github.com/tomnomnom/gron@latest
```

Comment: Hi @Gilles ... I tried to do this but due to the header at the beginning of the response, I got a failure: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 7. It is the "Why" I`m trying to isolate the JSON file!

Comment: Change the switches to remove headers. What is the curl command ?

Comment: I already tried too. "curl --no-include  --user..... command".. additionally, I have installed the curl from the brew library, and I cannot exclude the header. The same behavior for both software versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have converted the curl command to python code. It is easier to handle with the response.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = {
    'pretty': 'true',
}

json_data = {
    'autoScaling': {
        'diskGBEnabled': True,
    },
    'backupEnabled': False,
    'paused': True,
    'name': 'sdasdasd',
    'providerSettings': {
        'providerName': 'AWS',
        'instanceSizeName': 'M10',
        'regionName': 'US_EAST_2',
    },
}

response = requests.post(
    'https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/999999999999/clusters',
    params=params,
    headers=headers,
    json=json_data,
    auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'password'),
)

print(response.content)
```